# selecting aggregates on different filters in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's my query

```
  SELECT
    client_id,
   TimesTested,
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(30)) AS count,
    CAST(AVG(testfreq) as varchar(30)) as TestFreq,
    CAST(STDEV(TestFreq) as varchar(30)) Stdv
  FROM counted
  GROUP BY
    client_id,
    TimesTested
```

It works; however, i need filter the AVG and STDEV where testfreq>0 but I need the count(*) to be not filtered.

The closest thing would be:

```
  SELECT
    client_id,
   TimesTested,
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(30)) AS count,
    CAST(AVG(testfreq) as varchar(30)) as TestFreq,
    CAST(STDEV(TestFreq) as varchar(30)) Stdv
  FROM counted
  where testfreq>0  --however I don't want this filtered applied to count(*)
  GROUP BY
    client_id,
    TimesTested
```

Thanks so much for your guidance!

Comment: Why are you converting the results to character strings?  What is the type of `testfreq` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `CASE` statement in your aggregate similar to this:

```
SELECT client_id,
   TimesTested,
   CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(30)) AS count,
   CAST(AVG(case when testfreq>0 then testfreq end) as varchar(30)) as TestFreq,
   CAST(STDEV(case when testfreq>0 then TestFreq end) as varchar(30)) Stdv
FROM counted
GROUP BY client_id,  TimesTested
```

I am not sure why you need these as varchars, is there a reason you need these values converted to `varchar`?

I would just leave the values as is:

```
SELECT client_id,
   TimesTested,
   COUNT(*) AS count,
   AVG(case when testfreq>0 then testfreq end) as TestFreq,
   STDEV(case when testfreq>0 then TestFreq end) Stdv
FROM counted
GROUP BY client_id,  TimesTested
```